# Printing out multiple variables within the same print statement

Tags: xcode, swift

This code is not to be used in a app, it is simply for me to test some values in playground. Why am I not able to print several values within the same statement? My only previous programming knowledge is from python, and in python I believe this was possible with this notation, perhaps in swift it is different?

```
let array1 = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
let array2 = [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
for i in 0...11 {
    println(array1[i],\t,array2[i])
}
```

I want the output in the console to look like this:

```
1   2
1   2
1   2
etc..
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
println("\(array1[i]) \t \(array2[i])")
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, this has solved the problem, however I have found another, as the values I am using are not "1" and "2", they are words of different lengths, due to this they are offset. Do you know how to generate a column with a certain width so regardless of the length of a word, in the next column all words start at the same position.

Comment: I think there is no such a built-in functionality. You can search for padding string to the right by filling the left hand side with empty string so it will take always the same space. For example you have 'test' word and you extend it to contain 10 characters ('000000test') - zero is a blank string, and you have a one digit number, you can do the same - extend it to be 10 characters long ('0000000009') it will take the same space as your 'test' word.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use print with multiple arguments.

```
print(array1[i], "\t", array2[i])
```